# Deploy Symfony2 settings

Tags: php, symfony, deployment

I have been following this Symfony2 Deployment tutorial but I have run into problems. http://bordenia.wordpress.com/2012/04/14/deploying-your-symfony-2-0-web-app-to-the-production-server/

I am trying to set the /web/app.php as the root folder. It works fine as www.example.com/web but not as www.example.com as I would like.

I have uploaded all the files into the public_html folder on my server. /home/user/public_html/app for example. Should this all be in a separate folder for the project.

/home/user/public_html/project/app?

I understand the app.php file is held in public_html/web now I have tried to create a symlink to that folder on my server but it flags up this

Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'InvalidArgumentException' with message 'The file "/home/user/public_html/app/config/routing_prod.yml" does not exist.

So this doesn't seem to work because in order to do this you move the rooting files. Does this mean I need to update them with the new routing somewhere?

As for the other config files this is what I have.

I have set the parameters.yml up correctly cos I can send a contact form and access the database alright from www.example.com/web?!

The only code I have in the routing_prod.yml is this:

```
_main:
    resource: routing.yml
```

The tutorial said copy what you had in the _dev.yml and move it into the _prod.yml file.

In my routing.yml I have this

```
x_portfolio:
    resource: "@xPortfolioBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml"
    prefix:   /
```

Any thoughts appreciated...

Answer (score 0):

You need to upload your symfony2 application to folder upper that public_html.
So to folder /home/user/
Folder "web" rename to public_html (or create symlink).
Please notice that during generate assets you will need specify correct path of public folder (not "web" but public_html).